# How to execute commands on a bat file from c++

Tags: c++, batch-file, ffmpeg

I'm working in a c++ project and I need to call ffmpeg command prompt(ff-promt) from my c++ code and execute commands on that bat command line. I have already opened the window. but not functioning the command running on that bat window. Can anyone please guide me how to do it.
for opening I have used following command

```
FILE *bat = _popen("ffmpeg-2.5.2-win64-static\\ff-prompt", "w");
```

I used following command to write the command on that and enter

```
fprintf(bat, "ffmpeg -i Sample.avi -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192k -f mp3 Sample.mp3\r");
```

please guide me soon. Thanks

Comment: @person who down voted, please do it after adding at least putting a comment. Because that will be a big help. Because you know this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run your ffmpeg command by *system()* function from *cstdlib without bat file something like this:

```
    std::cout << "Executing ffmpeg command\n";
    i=system ("ffmpeg -i Sample.avi -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192k -f mp3 Sample.mp3");
    std::cout << "The value returned was: " << i << std::endl;
```

Comment: thanks DvoryankinEvgeny. should I add ffmpeg to my c++ project?

Comment: @AK47 You shouldn't add ffmpeg to project. You need to have installed ffmpeg on machine where you run your program and add path to executable ffmpeg to enviroment variable _PATH_